# Posting JSON data to FOSUserBundle Registration, Login, Profile, etc

Tags: php, ajax, json, symfony

I haven't seen any questions about sending requests by JSON to use FOSUserBundle's functions so I am posting this question. I have a Symfony2 project that is primarily designed for mobile use (AJAX too). I am using FOSRestBundle and FOSUserBundle which work well from the forms interface. However, I'd like to be able to register a user for example by posting JSON data to register, login, view profile, etc. How can this be done? Is it even possible to send JSON data to FOSUserBundle? If possible, I'd be glad if you could give an example of how to register or get the profile, etc.

Sample FOSUserBundle login form:

```
<form action="/projects/symfony/web/app_dev.php/login_check" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="1cdb2c8fa2fb9a52905ddebff3185ac1a3ad708d" />

<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="" required="required" />

<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" />

<input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
<label for="remember_me">Remember me</label>

<input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="Login" />
 </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a JSON example -  it detects if user is logged in or not 
the "code" is the response returned by the action,
the "imageHandler()" is the function that gets triggered using js in this case,for example using intervals or pressing a key.Of course it doesn't need parameters.
the send function is used to send variables to the controller, in this case im using it to send the "imageId" variable with the value given in the parameter(myImageId), same counts for myToDo.

Javascript (This is the twig template)

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      function imageHandler(myToDo,myimageId)
       { 
         var xml = ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) ?
             new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

         xml.open("GET", "{{path('imageHandler')}}", true); 
         xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json"); 

        xml.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            var serverResponse = JSON.parse(xml.responseText);

             if(serverResponse.code == 100 && serverResponse.success)
               {
                       //success
                }
             else if(serverResponse.code == 200) 
               {
                   //not logged in

                }

         } 
            xml.send({imageId: myimageId, toDo: myToDo});   
     }
    </script>


   /* This is the controller, the javascript knows which controller to call by using the "name    annotation"
    */

      /**
        * @Route(name="imageHandler")
        */
        public function imageHandlerAjaxAction(Request $request)
        {
            //If user is not logged in..
            if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) 
            {
                //return this variables (your choice of course, format: variable=>value)
                $response = array("code"=>200,"success"=>false);

                return new Response(json_encode($response));
            }
       }
```

Comment: Also if you want I can give you the same JS code using JQuery

Comment: thanks for trying to helpout. However, what I am trying to do is to understand with an example on how to post data in JSON to create a user in Symfony where the User table is managed by FOSUserBundle. For example, I know the login form is as posted above, now suppose I want to register and the route is /register, how do I send JSON to that route in order to register the specified user??